# How to Combine Excel files that contain valid tables and Remap column Names - Power Query Function

Tags: powerquery

I’m making a Power Query (M Code) that combines all Sheets in Workbooks stored in a folder. The logic is the following

1. Read folder content
2. Form a list of Workbooks(Sheets) within
3. Invoke a Function to “Format” content of each Sheet to append the records in a consolidated table

The invoked Function on every Sheet should:

- Identify where the “Titles" Row is located
- Remove “n” records until “Titles" Row
- Remap “Titles" to a standard Name from HeaderMap table
- Reorder the columns according to HeaderMap table
- Promote the “Titles” Row to Columns Headers
- Change column types according to HeaderMap table
- Remove “Blank” records

The caveat is that I may encounter Sheets that have no useful information. I need to peek inside the Sheet to verify if valid content and then execute the function to format. How can I Skip the Sheet when consolidating all tables? Something like

- Identify indexed row where the “Titles” are located
- **If** (no valid “Titles” found) **then Skip Sheet**
- **else** (continue with remaining steps)

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Once you have your list of tables, filter the list to exclude the one's with no usable data.

Comment: (Ron Rosenfeld), Precisely, I would like to peek inside the table first, to see if it is useful and then execute the function to format the content. For that, I should filter the records and determine if the first 1-2 titles contain valid information to process the entire table.